# how to check if 2 Jradiobutton are selected?

Tags: java, oop, jradiobutton

how can i check is 2 jRadio button are selected and then show a new frame showing the new operation in the new frame ,the problem in my code is that is show the question 1 even if non of radio button is selected 
[the program should check id addition and easy are selected and when click start test should show new frame](http://postimg.org/image/yfqsd52lr/)

this is my main code

```
     package javaapplication78;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class javaapplication78{
JFrame f1;
JPanel panel1,panel2,panel3,panel4;
JButton b1,b2;
JLabel label_1,label_2;
JRadioButton radio_1,radio_2,radio_3,radio_4,radio_5,radio_6,radio_7;

javaapplication78(){

JFrame f1 = new JFrame ("MathTest - Main Menu");
f1.setVisible(true);
f1.setSize(300,400);
f1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
panel1.add(new JLabel("Select a test type"));
panel1.add(radio_1=new JRadioButton("Addition"));
panel1.add(new JLabel(""));
panel1.add(radio_2=new JRadioButton("Substraction"));
panel1.add(new JLabel(""));
panel1.add(radio_3=new JRadioButton("Multiplication"));
panel1.add(new JLabel(""));
panel1.add(radio_4=new JRadioButton("Division"));

panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
panel2.add(new JLabel("select a diffculty level"));
panel2.add(radio_5=new JRadioButton("easy "));
panel2.add(new JLabel(""));
panel2.add(radio_6=new JRadioButton("moderate"));
panel2.add(new JLabel(""));
panel2.add(radio_7=new JRadioButton("hard"));

panel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
panel3.add(new JLabel(""));

JButton b1 = new JButton("Start test");      
panel3.add(b1);
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

new javaapplication79();

    }
});


  panel4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
  panel4.add(b2=new JButton("    exit    "));

  f1.add(panel1);
  f1.add(panel2);
  f1.add(panel3);
  f1.add(panel4);

  f1.add(label_1); 
  f1.add(radio_1);
  f1.add(radio_2);
  f1.add(radio_3); 
  f1.add(radio_4); 

  f1.add(label_2);
  f1.add(radio_5);
  f1.add(radio_6); 
  f1.add(radio_7);
  b1 = new JButton();
  b2 = new JButton();
  f1.add(b1); 
  f1.add(b2);   
    }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    javaapplication78 xyz =new javaapplication78();

  }
}
```

and this is frame code 
    package javaapplication78;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class javaapplication79{
JFrame f1;
JPanel panel1,panel4;
JLabel label_1;
JTextField t1;

 javaapplication79(){
f1 = new JFrame ("MathTest - Test Page");
f1.setVisible(true);
f1.setSize(400,150);
f1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
panel1.add(new JLabel("Question 1     14  -  5  = "));
panel1.add(new JTextField(10));
panel1.add(new JButton("Submit Answer"));



panel4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
panel4.add(new JButton("   Cancel Test   "));
f1.add(panel1);
f1.add(panel4);
f1.add(label_1); 

}

}
```

Comment: radio buttons are designed to select only one. use check boxes for multiple section.

Comment: set the default value for each radio group initially then there is no case when none of radio buttons are selected

Answer (score 1):

Put some precoditions like

`radio_1.isSelected();` returns true when selected.

`radio_1.getText()` if it is already selected, check for the selected value like this (value ='Y' or 'N')

Comment: why i have to use radio_1.getText() i don't have any value ?

Comment: @user3615990 Just in case you need the value of the name of the radio button. It's an OOP design with the JRadioButton Object. I think Sireesh nailed it! I would add a button or action Listener.